# Recommend backup software that will do true incremental backups of very large files

Tags: windows-7, backup

I am looking for inexpensive backup software that will do true incremental backups of really large files.  I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

I use a lot of virtual machines which, as you know, are virtual incarnations of whole hard disks which are, of course, very large.

I also have a 2 gigabyte outlook.pst file.

I want software that can do a full backup of these files once and then backup only the parts of the files that change after that without degradation of the files.

Can you recommend any software.  I googled and found [this](http://www.backup4all.com/en/) sofware which seems to promise what I want. Or maybe all modern backup packages (like syncback) will do this.

In my experience and incremental backup backs up the changed files not the change portion of the file.  But I also know that incremental backups of partial files are possible because programs like Dropbox and Jungle Disk do this.  (I am not inquiring about internet backups...I already do that but only with my key files.  There is too much data to do that with virtual drives.)

Any insight will be appreciated.  What do you guys recommend to your friends and customers.

Seth

Comment: You're misunderstanding and misquoting what an incremental backup is. What you're referring to is a block level backup.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Genie Backup Manager. I used it long time ago and it does decent job with incremental backups. I didn't use it for any VM though.

http://www.genie-soft.com/Business/genie_backup_manager_Pro/Feature.aspx

Comment: Genie Timeline will do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Altaro Oops!Backup](http://www.altaro.com/) for some time and would definitely recommend it.
After doing an initial full backup it [backs up the parts of files that have changed](http://www.altaro.com/smb-backup-reversedelta.php). It also builds a full copy of the most recent version from the diff file for safety. So you should see the initial and the latest versions of your files but only diff files for intermediate versions.

There's a 30 day trial version.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Acronis True Image Home](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) ($50).

I use it to back up entire drives (mostly for easy reinstallation on new machines) but it can also do incremental backups to existing images and block-level copying of specific files.

And of course it allows you to restore individual files from images, not just restoring the whole image.

Answer (score 0):

[Cobian backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm)

[Delta Copy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)

[Backup Maker](https://www.ascomp.de/index.php?php=prog&page=desc&prog=backupmaker&controller=products&action=show&product=backupmaker&tab=desc)

[AceBackup](http://www.acebackup.com/)

[Microsoft SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en)

[Personal Backup](http://personal-backup.rathlev-home.de/index-e.html)

[Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/screenshot.html)

[Areca Backup](http://www.areca-backup.org/)

Comment: Posted and may not apply to this question exactly but another similar  thread was closed and pointed here, is there a backup solution wiki?...http://superuser.com/questions/262354/good-free-backup-tool-with-incremental-backup-feature

Answer (score -1):

[SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/downloads.html) should support this as well, not positive but when it comes to backups this is what I use for all of my customers. It has been a little since I have had to set up incremental backups but I remember it being the solution I used for that customer.

Comment: Syncback does incremental file level backups, not block-level backups.